# Calculating Albedo for Landsat 8 using QGIS with GRASS?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, reflectance, surface, grass-7.2

I am trying to estimate albedo for Landsat 8 OLI. The idea was to use the GRASS function i.albedo within the processing toolbox of QGIS. However, the option for Landsat 8 OLI is not available, therefore I tried to use directly GRASS GIS. Being unfamiliar with GRASS I could not figure this out.

Steps I followed.

1. More Downloaded DN value images from UGSG Earthexplore website. (I want to use the Surface Reflectance Higher-Level Data Products from USGS which makes steps 2-3 redundant, but the values were off when I tried. I had read that the values stored in this product needs to be multipled by a factor, ex. 0.0001, so that I can use this product?)
2. Performed TOA (Top-ofAtmosphere) reflectance conversion from DNs (wanted to use GRASS function i.landsat.toar but could not figure this out, used semi-automatic classification plugin for QGIS instead.
3. Wanted surface reflectance so I applied DOS1 correction within the above plugin.
4. Cannot calculate from surface reflectance to Albedo for Landsat 8?

If I could do this within QGIS it would be best, or if someone is familiar with GRASS GIS, I could use a simple tutorial.

[Remote Sensing Landsat Surface Reflectance and Albedo](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/231528/remote-sensing-landsat-surface-reflectance-and-albedo)

Comment: I have found another way to calculate albedo from landsat 8, but it uses the R programming language. Follow this link https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/water/vignettes/METRIC_advanced.html.

Answer (score 1):

The [grass72 version of i.albedo](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass72/manuals/i.albedo.html) supports (now) for Landsat8 imagery.